# recommend php library for parsing and modifying dom

Tags: php, dom

i have to modify dom. i.e. remove few elements and add few. kindly recommend any php library that can parse and modify DOM.

Comment: Did you try the PHP manual? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Are you referring to XML or HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
- A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way!
- Require PHP 5+.
- Supports invalid HTML.
- Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery.
- Extract contents from HTML in a single line.
```

Or official:

[Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)